# nginx nodejs+pm2 return connot GET /pm2

Tags: node.js, nginx, pm2

I installed nginx to serve multiple nodejs apps

On my server I have 2 apps myapp and pm2-web

the nginx config look like this

```
http {
    # .... logs, gzip ... etc
    server {
        location / {
           proxy_pass http://localhost:5000;
           proxy_http_version 1.1;
           proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
           proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
           proxy_set_header Host $host;
           proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
        }

        location /pm2 {
           proxy_pass http://localhost:9000;
           proxy_http_version 1.1;
           proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
           proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
           proxy_set_header Host $host;
           proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
        }

    }
```

my app runs fine but when I try to access `/pm2`

I get the following error

```
Cannot GET /pm2
```

when pm2-web is not running I get `502 Bad Gateway`

But I can still access pm2 from `http://IP:9000`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `/pm2` part of the URL is being passed through to your Node application, where it does not match any paths.

ie, your pm2 app is running on `9000`, but you are trying to access `http://localhost:9000/pm2` which doesn't exist.

Include a trailing slash in your proxy pass URL to ensure `/pm2` is not being included:

```
location /pm2 {
   proxy_pass http://localhost:9000/;
   proxy_http_version 1.1;
   proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
   proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
   proxy_set_header Host $host;
   proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
}
```

Comment: with `rewrite ^/pm2(.*)$ $1 last;` I get `error 500` and with `rewrite ^/pm2(.*) /$1 break;` I get `pm2-web version {{version}}`

Comment: it returns `pm2-web version {{version}}` i think it is because the server can't find the static file `css|js` ... etc